# Programmatically add an alert for a user in Sharepoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, alerts

We have an Office 365/Sharepoint Online instance, and a complicated Ticket system that we've migrated there. However, we don't seem to have the ability to set up "Everyone" to receive alerts when they're *listed* in a ticket (via custom fields). We could manually add each and every person in the company to a list view to accomplish what we want, but that is both tedious and silly. I've done some research, and talked with a consultant, and it appears that we may not have access to create Alerts any other way than manually.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue? I don't care if the solution is .NET, Powershell, or even fancy javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to set up user alerts for specific lists with PowerShell. However, StackOverflow is not a free script-writing consultancy service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Mathias could you give me a hint? I have found the only way how to work with user alerts in SharePoint Online: web service /_vti_bin/alerts.asmx. But it supports only GetAlerts and DeleteAlert operations.